# How to a cut out a hob hole in a kitchen worktop with a router?

Tags: kitchen-counters, routers

I have a T5 router and can get a [1/4-Inch Shank Double Flute 50mm long Straight Grooving Bit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08L3CV1BZ/?coliid=IJVWVSTJSB0UW&colid=3QOASHI02WCF7&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it&th=1), clearly, I will need to make many passes as the router/bit would not cope with a single deep pass.

I have a 20mm Guide Bush and can get some MDF to make a guild.   I have a selection of normal bit, but don't have a 20mm bit but could easily get one.

How do I make the required guilds and fix them to the worktop etc?

Comment: Seems you know what you need.  Is the question missing a section, that did not get posted?

Comment: The worktop is probably on the nice side.  Would make internal guild(router cuts on the outside), so attachment(screws/nails/glue) does not mar the finish on the rest of the top.  An external guild will probably require clamping somehow.

Comment: @crip659  Internal guild is clearly easier to make and fix, but if the router slips at any point then it will cut into the worktop rather than into the cutout.

Comment: what kind of HOB hole, what is the size

Answer (score 1):

The last one I did with a jigsaw.

Worked fine, measure twice & cut once.

Support the waste on the last cut.

Edit:
And to reduce or avoid a rough edge on the surface, I would deeply score the cut line first.

Comment: I trying to advoid having to buy a jigsaw.

Comment: I generally use some #6 drywall screws to hold the template in place. It only takes a few and if you can do it on the back no holes to fill.

Comment: To the OP, if you can overcome your aversion, the jigsaw is actually the right tool for the task. Pushing a little router to do a task like this is hard on the tool, messy, and slow. Use a downcut blade if you go with the jigsaw. And if you must have a template for the router, you can hold it down with hot glue or doublesided tape.

Comment: Agreed a jig saw is the best tool to start with.  Last time I did one, I put down a couple of wide strips of blue tape on all four sides to protect the countertop, then used the template to trace where the cut needed to go. Then you have 2 choices:  if you're ok with a rough edge (which will be hidden), cut very close to the line.  If you're picky and want a smooth opening, cut a bit to the inside of the line (say 1/4"), then clamp a board as a guide to for the router with a straight cutting bit, repeat for all 4 sides.

Comment: BTW, and this is conversational, sorry, but were did you blokes from across the pond come up with the term "hob" for a cooktop? I'm like, wtf is a hob? First time I saw that, I had to look it up on Google!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson - where did you guys get 'broiler' from? The same has happened with many terms that separated after the settlement of the N. Am. continent. Look at all the names for parts of cars; no common ground at all there. You guys couldn't even agree to follow the international change in the spelling of aluminium & stuck with the original, wrongly derived term. [all the others in that family of metals are 'ium', not 'um'.] … and you still use inches :P Hob is a medieval term for 'utensil holder near fireplace', but was co-opted when actual cookers/stoves were invented.